# UISplitViewController selector not recognized from MasterViewController

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a custom UISplitViewController, created so I can present a login screen to the user. In this controller I also have a logout method.

The logout button is in the navigation bar of the MasterViewController. When the user clicks logout, I am trying to call the UISplitViewControllers logoutUser method. First I tried:

```
[self.splitViewController logoutUser:self];
```

This gave errors when trying to compile:

No visible @interface for 'UISplitViewController' declares the selector 'logoutUser:'
I then commented out the offending line and added the following if, checking to see if indeed my UISplitViewController responds to the selector.

```
if([self.splitViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(logoutUser:)]){
   // [self.splitViewController logoutUser:self];
    NSLog(@"Selector");
}else{
    NSLog(@"No Selector");
}
```

In the log when running I get Selector. uncommenting the [self.splitViewController logoutUser:self] I get the same error.

I tried to clean the build and rebuild but it still gives this error. How cna I resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As commented above, I found the answer:

```
 [self.splitViewController performSelector:@selector(logoutUser:) withObject:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that self.splitViewController is of the base splitViewController and the compiler is not able to find the logoutUser method. However, at runtime the splitViewController can respond to the method.
As you said your splitViewController is custom, try casting to the custom controller:

[(yourCustomViewController *)self.splitViewController logoutUser:self];

Comment: I tried it gives the same error. However, after more googling I found that I can use: [self.splitViewController performSelector:@selector(logoutUser:) withObject:self];

Comment: @user207788: maybe you forgot to import the header for your custom view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Any message can be sent to any object in Objective-C, as long as the method is declared somewhere in the current scope (i.e. it is declared in some class in some header that is imported).

There could be two problems you are referring to:

1. You did not import a header that contains the method. (The class it's declared in doesn't even have to be the same as the class you're calling it on now; it just has to be declared *somewhere*.) In this case, you will get a warning that the method is not found, and it will assume that the method returns type `id`. You can fix this by importing the header of your custom view controller.
2. Since `self.splitViewController` is type `UISplitViewController *`, and `logoutUser:` is not a method of `UISplitViewController`, you may get a *warning* (not error) that it may not respond to that method. This is a result of static type checking because `UISplitViewController *` is a concrete type. You can fix this by either

   1. Casting it to a type that does support that method, as Enrique's answer suggests; or
   2. Casting it to type `id` so it does not do static type checking, e.g.

   `[(id)self.splitViewController logoutUser:self];`